# Loop infinito addTextChangedListener Android

Tags: java, android

En el Create de mi Actividad , tengo lo siguiente

```
entidadFinanciera.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

el cual hace

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        // no se necesita
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        // no se necesita
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        filtro(s.toString());

    }
};
```

Filtro :

```
private void filtro(String s) {

    entidadFinanciera.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    Spinner spinerBancos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.imgpayment);

    int cantidad = bancos.size();
    bancosCopia = bancos ;
    int iterador = 0 ;
    final ArrayList<String> bancosAux = new ArrayList<>();
    while(iterador<cantidad){
        if(bancos.get(iterador).contains(s)){
            bancosAux.add(bancos.get(iterador));
        }
        iterador++;
    }


    final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapte = new ArrayAdapter<>(Registry.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, bancosAux);
    dataAdapte.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinerBancos.setAdapter(dataAdapte);
    spinerBancos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object agencia = dataAdapte.getItem(position);
            String agenciaSeleccionada  = agencia.toString();
            EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEntidadFinanciera) ;
            numeroDeEntidad = agenciaSeleccionada.substring(0,3).trim();
            edit.setText(agenciaSeleccionada.substring(4,agenciaSeleccionada.length()));
            bancos = bancosCopia;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
            // no se necesita
        }
    });


    entidadFinanciera.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

}
```

En pocas palabras , Tengo un EDITTEXT , donde escribo el filtro y cargo eso a un spinner , y una vez elegido algo de ese SPINNER colocarlo en el EDITTEXT , pero este se me queda en un bucle infinito , intente eliminarlo al prinicpio al escuchador y volver a meterlo a lo ultimo pero aun asi sige siendo un bucle

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Loop infinito addTextChangedListener](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129901/loop-infinito-addtextchangedlistener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas eliminando el `TextWatcher` al inicio del método pero lo agregas al final:

```
private void filtro(String s) {

    entidadFinanciera.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    //...

    entidadFinanciera.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
```

Por lo que es como si no hicieras nada.

Quizas lo que necesites eliminar el TextWatcher antes de editar el texto del EditText y agregarlo una vez editado. Esto seria en el metodo `setOnItemSelectedListener`:

```
private void filtro(String s) {

    //...
    spinerBancos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            //...
            // eliminamos el Watcher para que no se ejecute
            edit.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
            edit.setText(agenciaSeleccionada.substring(4,agenciaSeleccionada.length()));
            bancos = bancosCopia;

            // le agregamos el watchers para que el usuario pueda buscar mas filtro al escribir
            entidadFinanciera.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
            // no se necesita
        }
    });

}
```

Codigo completo:

```
private void filtro(String s) {

Spinner spinerBancos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.imgpayment);

int cantidad = bancos.size();
bancosCopia = bancos ;
int iterador = 0 ;
final ArrayList<String> bancosAux = new ArrayList<>();
while(iterador<cantidad){
    if(bancos.get(iterador).contains(s)){
        bancosAux.add(bancos.get(iterador));
    }
    iterador++;
}


final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapte = new ArrayAdapter<>(Registry.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, bancosAux);
dataAdapte.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinerBancos.setAdapter(dataAdapte);
spinerBancos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object agencia = dataAdapte.getItem(position);
        String agenciaSeleccionada  = agencia.toString();
        EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEntidadFinanciera);


        numeroDeEntidad = agenciaSeleccionada.substring(0,3).trim();

        // eliminamos el Watcher para que no se ejecute
        edit.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        edit.setText(agenciaSeleccionada.substring(4,agenciaSeleccionada.length()));
        bancos = bancosCopia;

        // le agregamos el watchers para que el usuario pueda buscar mas filtro al escribir
        entidadFinanciera.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
        // no se necesita
    }
});

}
```

Comment: te quedo cortado la ultima oracion ?

Comment: Perdon, debi de eliminarla despues de la edicion. Gracias por la observacion.

Comment: el unico tema de esto es que en si no deja de hacer el loop, sige con el mismo problema